# I can't find the installed application (HDSentinel_GUI) anywhere

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I've downloaded and installed HDSentinel GUI tar package but I can't see it in the application panel. Where can I find it?

I've installed it as below:

```
tar -xvf hdsentinel_gui64bit.tar.xz
cd HDSentinel_GUI
sudo ./install.sh
```

Content of install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo ""
echo "Unzip the HDSentinel_GUI archive to /home/your user name/HDSentinel_Light/"
echo ""
##Unzip the HDSentinel_GUI archive
unzip HDSentinel_GUI.zip -d ~/
echo ""
echo "Copy icon the icon folder"
echo ""
##Copy icon the icon folder
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/HDSentinel_GUI.ico -t /usr/share/icons
echo "Set owner and permission for icon"
echo ""
##Set owner and permission for icon
sudo chmod 444 /usr/share/icons/HDSentinel_GUI.ico
echo "Make directory 'usr/share/bin' if not present"
echo ""
##make directory usr/share/bin if not present
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/bin
echo "Premission for folder"
echo ""
##premission for folder
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/share/bin
echo "Copy to bin library"
echo ""
##Copy the bin folder
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/HDSentinel_GUI -t /usr/share/bin
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/HDSentinel -t /usr/share/bin
echo "Set premission for application"
echo ""
##Set premission for application
sudo chmod a+rwx /usr/share/bin/HDSentinel_GUI
sudo chmod a+rwx /usr/share/bin/HDSentinel
echo "Make directory for user menu if not present"
echo ""
##Make directory for user menu if not present
sudo mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
echo "Copy launcher to user menu"
echo ""
##Copy launcher to user menu
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop -t ~/.local/share/applications
echo "Set premission for menu launcher"
echo ""
##set premission for menu launcher
sudo chmod a+rwx ~/.local/share/applications/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop
echo "Copy launcher to Asztal if present"
echo ""
##copy launcher to desktop
##sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop -t ~/Asztal
##echo "Copy launcher to Desktop if present"
echo ""
##copy launcher to desktop eng
##sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop -t ~/Desktop
echo ""
##echo "Set premission for launcher (Desktop)"
echo ""
##Set premission for launcher
##sudo chmod a+rwx ~/Desktop/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop
echo ""
##echo "Set premission for launcher (Asztal)"
echo ""
##set premission for launcher
##sudo chmod a+rwx ~/Asztal/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop
echo "Remove install temp directory (/home/your user name/HDSentinel_GUI/)"
##Remove ~/HDSentinel_GUI directory
rm -d -rf ~/HDSentinel_GUI
```

Comment: What steps did you follow to install it?

Comment: I'll add it to original question.

Comment: Could you include the content of the `ìnstall.sh` file?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls ~/.local/share/applications | grep -i Hard`

Comment: Did the install procedure produce any errors? From that file, you should have a desktop shortcut.

Comment: There was no error but I don't have a desktop icon.
@Someone this turns out nothing. I just installed ubuntu few hours ago.

Comment: Is there any directory named `HDSentinel_GUI` in your `~/` directory?

Comment: That is home directory, right? No, there isn't.

Comment: @AndrewHarlan Try running: `sudo unzip ~/Downloads/HDSentinel_GUI.zip -d ~/`.

Comment: No such file or directory it says. Actually I found it at usr/share/bin directory.

Comment: Where is the `.zip` file of HDSentinel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133924/discussion-between-andrew-harlan-and-someone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there were some errors with the installation script ie. There was no `.zip` file in `~/` for the desktop launchers.  **We fixed the error in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133924/discussion-between-andrew-harlan-and-someone).**

Here are the steps we followed:

1. Reinstall the application:

   ```
   cd /tmp && wget https://www.hdsentinel.com/hdslin/hdsentinel_gui64bit.tar.xz && tar -xvf hdsentinel_gui64bit.tar.xz && cd HDSentinel_GUI && sudo ./install.sh
   ```
2. The `~/` directory now had a directory named `HD_Sentinel_GUI`.
3. Next, we created a launcher file at desktop and the applications overview:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop ~/Desktop
   ```
4. Next, we gave executable permissions to the file so that it won't open with a text editor:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop
   ```
5. Next, we created a desktop launcher for the Applications Overview:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/Desktop/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop /usr/share/applications/
   ```

Now, the app was appearing as a launcher and was working as expected!

Answer (score 2):

The script copied the executable files to `/usr/share/bin/`:

```
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/HDSentinel_GUI -t /usr/share/bin
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/HDSentinel -t /usr/share/bin
```

The "launcher" (a `.desktop` file) was copied to `/.local/share/applications/`.

```
sudo cp ~/HDSentinel_GUI/Hard_Disk_Sentinel_GUI.desktop -t ~/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: When I double click on the .desktop file, it opens with text editor. Shouldn't it suppose to launch the application instead?